# How to stop a website from automatically taking me out of fullscreen mode

Tags: video, fullscreen, window-focus

I was wondering if there was a way to prevent a website from taking me out of fullscreen mode?  I use TubePlus.me and they serve ads on their pages - revenue - I get that.  However, when I watch a video and put the page into fullscreen mode, sometimes you can see the video start to "lag" or "stutter" throughout the video...  and then many times right after it does this, the page minimizes out of fullscreen mode.  My guess is this is happening so their ads will be seen again, because in fullscreen mode no ads can be seen / heard, etc.  How do I prevent this from happening and persistently stay in fullscreen?

After doing a little more checking, it appears the videos on the page are delivered in Flash - I have ver 12.0.0.77.  It is possible that something in Flash is being exploited to minimize the screen??

Another possibility is my anti-virus.. (Rarely, but I have had my anti-virus activate when using the same site that is minimizing - TubePlus.me) I am using Kaspersky Internet Security 2013. I know it has a System Watcher feature that could possibly be doing this. Per their help section:

•Controls executable files started from vulnerable applications and web browsers (for example, an attempt to run an executable file by a program designed for viewing documents).

•Controls suspicious actions of vulnerable applications (for example, if the rights of a running vulnerable application are exceeded and it writes itself into the other processes’ system memory).

•Monitors previous program starts (for example, whether the program was started by the user or by an exploit).

•Tracks a source of a malicious code (for example, a web browser that started download of an infected file; remote web address).

•Prevents using application vulnerabilities.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if the owners of that site want you to exit the fullscreen-mode, there is less to nothing, that you can do.

So I would recommend you to use an adblocker like [AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/de/firefox). This way, you can block the ads and maybe also stop the website to force you to exit fullscreen-mode.

**Update**

Maybe you should be able to disable javascript to disable that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't visit the site at work I'm going to assume the full screen is achieved using Javascript.

Depending on what the technology is, you *may* be able to just disable Javascript to prevent the full screen(normal size screen) from being trigged... Of course this may have other negative affects if the destination page requires Javascript to function (but that isn't your question)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, the information is obviously outdated.  Flash is long gone and dead.  I'm making this answer as a Wiki so it can be updated over time instead of having 1000 outdated answers.

As for full-screen, you can only toggle that via javascript if some user interaction event is what executes the code.  You can't go full screen on page load, it has to be a user decision like clicking a link (although nothing stops you from making a fake ad and going full-screen when they try to close it).

Clicking a link exits full-screen.  The only way I know of to get around it, is to design the site using ajax for everything (or an iframe). The design is supposed to reduce the power of malicious web sites, but they seem to have botched some user options as well.

Answer (score -1):

The website is probably implemented that way. As in javascript might be the cause.
Just as I tried to research I found [this](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/7645-script-to-automatically-display-webpage-in-fullscreen).
What this page shows is that a javascript code can simply make a webpage force your browser to open the site in fullscreen.
For similar reasons, a code can reverse it as well.

What I will suggest is(for chrome):
1. Type `chrome://settings/content` in the address bar.
2. Under the javascript section- Check  `Do not allow any site to run JavaScript`.

Hope this will solve your issue.